# C# : Stack Overflow Exception during recursive method

Tags: c#, random, stack, overflow

I have a recursive method that calls itself whenever the random generated number isn't equal to 1.
I'm trying to test odds on different things such as a shiny pokemon (1/8192) or a 12-eyes seed in Minecraft (10^12), even though I understand why the Stack Overflow is happening, I don't know how to fix it. Using Threads slows it down by a lot (5000 calculations/s without, around 500 with threading).

Here's the code:

```c#
static void shiny()
{
    total = 0;
    counter += 1;
    resetcounter += 1;
    if (rdm.Next(8192) + 1 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SHINY !! In: " + counter + " resets.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (resetcounter > 7000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reset. Current: " + counter);
            ThreadStart newtask = new ThreadStart(shiny);
            Thread task = new Thread(newtask);
            task.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reset. Current: " + counter);
            shiny();
        }
    }
}
```

I use the resetcounter variable to avoid the Stack Overflow error since it's happening around 7k "resets", then it starts a new thread.
I'd love to understand how testing odds can avoid stack overflow though !

Comment: Why is this recursive and not a simple loop with a break condition?

Comment: Ohh I haven't thought of that, guess I'm small brain haha ! The loop indeed works, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

for some background info. C# and many other languages uses a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) when calling methods, this is used for local variables, return values and other stuff. The size of the stack will therefore increase when you call a method, and decreases the same amount when the method returns. The max size is usually 1-4Mb and is quite easy to reach when using recursive code without a well defined max depth.

Recursive functions can be re-written as iterative functions. Some cases need an explicit [stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netcore-3.1) that can be much larger, but that is not needed in this case. The example code, minus the threading, could be rewritten as follows:

```
    void shiny()
    {
        while (rdm.Next(8192) != 0)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SHINY !! In: " + counter + " resets.");
    }
```

While experiments like this can be fun, you can calculate probabilities explicitly. Assuming the chance of finding a shiny in one round is one in 8192, or 0.012%, the chance of finding at least one shiny after n rounds would be 1 - (8191/8192)^n. Throw that into wolfram alpha and you get a [probability plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20-%20%288191%2F8192%29%5Ex%20%20in%20range%200%20to%2030000).